# Printing multiple files on one page with Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, template-design

I have made a template for a small sign that will label cafe foods, but I can't find the best solution to print more than one sign on a page. The signs are about 3 by 2 inches, and I'd love to fill a standard letter sized sheet with them. Sounds simple- but I'm obviously missing something?

Comment: Is each "sign" a separate file, layer or artboard? How are they arranged now?

Answer (score 2):

As a quick fix, you can wrap artboards within artboards, take aa look at this example. Here I have a file with 4 artboards (1 hidden off screen that won't be used)

[image: artboard1]

I can wrap a larger artboard around these 4, like so:

[image: artboard2]

Then when I go to print (`cmd + p`), I can set the range to only print that final artboard. In my case (`6`), depending on how close the boards are, you may have to use `scale to fit` or just move them closer.
[image: print screen]

Comment: Although this is an interesting solution, you didn't explain how to create new artboards: "Document Setup" -> "Edit Artboards" -> then draw a new artboard.

Comment: @paulmz I did not think it was needed, since the user has already created multiple designs, one would assume they have an understanding of how to create artboards with the tool.